# How to know that http redirect + form POST is successful

Tags: http, http-post, wildfly, wicket, http-redirect

My wicket web application is performing a form POST + redirection to a given URL. That aims to redirect the user to that URL and posting information the server hosting the URL.
Is there any solution to know that the redirection succeeds or fails. The point is that as soon as we do the redirection, we don't know if the user has seen the target web page or not.
Below is the web page performing the redirection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Redirection Page</title>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: hidden;">
            <form wicket:id="customerForm" id="redirectForm"  method="post">
                <input wicket:id="param1" type="hidden"/>
                <input wicket:id="param2" type="hidden"/>
                <input wicket:id="param3" type="hidden"/>
             </form>
           <script language="javascript">
                document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Web application is developed using wicket 6.27.0 along with JEE7, and hosted in wildfly 10

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a flag in the Session in MyForm#onSubmit() and read+delete it in the GET endpoint.
If your application is stateless then you can use a custom cookie instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The application is stateless. How can I deal with the custom cookie solution? The URL in my end does not display anything to the user. Its only purpose is to fire a back-end logic then redirect the user to the target URL.

Comment: Write a Cookie in the response after POST and read+delete the cookie in the page responsible for GET